# Rooting acer liquid mini with Ubuntu?

Tags: rooting, linux

can someone explain how to root android phone using ubuntu or any linux distro please? There are so many app like superoneclick, z4root etc..but android is based on linux right? so it should be easy to root with linux...but how? i'm using acer liquid mini 2.2.

Comment: use super one click. It worked with acer liquid mini...Acer custom ROM can be found here [link] (http://acer-club.ru/topic/10684-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-acefirmware-liquid-mini-e310-custom-rom/)

Answer (score 3):

[Super One Click](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=803682) is written in C#. You need Mono to run it under Linux and other Non-Windows platforms. You can check your Ubuntu Package Manager for Mono or download it from [here](http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html).

The XDA-Forum-Link also has a link to a detailed description on [how to make it work under Linux](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8699742&postcount=537).

I have never personally used it on Linux, but once the program is up and running, it should be very self explanatory.